# Retrieving a value with multiple conditions - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Sample date:

Dataframe 1

| cusip_id | trd_exctn_dt | time_to_maturity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00077AA2 | 2015-05-09 | 1.20 years |
| 00077TBO | 2015-05-06 | 3.08 years |

Dataframe 2:

| Index | SVENY01 | SVENY02 | SVENY03 | SVENY04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-05-09 | 1.35467 | 1.23367 | 1.52467 | 1.89467 |
| 2015-05-08 | 1.65467 | 1.87967 | 1.43251 | 1.98765 |
| 2015-05-07 | 1.35467 | 1.76567 | 1.90271 | 1.43521 |
| 2015-05-06 | 1.34467 | 1.35417 | 1.67737 | 1.11167 |

Desired output:

I am wanting to exactly match the 'trd_exctn_dt' in df1 with the date in the index of df2, whilst at the same time matching the 'time_to_maturity' in df1 with the nearest SVENYXX in df2 (rounded up e.g. 1.20 years would be equivalent to SVENY02). For example, for cusip_id (00077AA2), the trd_exctn_dt is 2015-05-09 and the time_to_maturity is 1.20 years. As this is the case I want to obtain the corresponding value in df2 with the date of 2015-05-09 in the column SVENY02.

I want to repeat this for several cusip_ids, how would I achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Downvoted as your question does not contain any code. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my solution code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

SVENYXX = []
for i in range(df1['cusip_id'].shape[0]):
    cusip_id = df1['cusip_id'][i]
    trd_exctn_date = df1['trd_exctn_dt'][i]
    maturity_time = df1['time_to_maturity'][i]
    
    svenyVals = df2.loc[trd_exctn_date]
    closestSvenyVal = svenyVals.iloc[(svenyVals-maturity_time).abs().argsort()[0]]
    
    SVENYXX.append(closestSvenyVal)
```

where `df1` is Dataframe 1, `df2` is Dataframe 2, and `SVENYXX` is the list with all the closest SVENYXX values to the given `cusip_id`.

I loop through all the `cusip_id`'s and obtain the correspond `trd_exctn_dt` and `time_to_maturity` values. Then with the extracted data, I find the corresponding row in DataFrame 2, and then by finding the lowest difference in `svenyVals` compared to `time_to_maturity`, I append that value to the `SVENYXX` list.

Comment: Is SVENYXX and df2 the same in your code? Because I have the SVENYXX values on an excel spreadsheet and have imported them into my code as a new df

Comment: @lds1 No, they are not the same. `SVENYXX` is just the list of the closest SVENY values in `df2` for a given `cusip_id`. `df2` is exactly like Dataframe 2 in your question. Feel free to call the `SVENYYXX` variable `closestSvenyyValues` or whatever you prefer!

Comment: this code does not seem to work. Instead, could I initially create a new dataframe by merging the df1 and df2 together (left_on = 'trd_exctn_dt', right_on = 'Date') and from there use the 'time_to_maturity' (rounded up) to match with the closest SVENYXX . If so, how would I go about the question this way?

Comment: @lds1 What exactly is your error causing the code not to work?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: Ahh it seems that `df2` becomes a list somewhere in your code. The `loc` function only applies to DataFrames and not lists.

Comment: Would there be an alternative way of approaching this question?